# set pdf width and height according to image width and height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I want to set the PDF width and height equal to the image width and height. But the image width and height is coming as 0.

I also used `image.onload()` but that is not getting called.

This is HTML:

```
<span class="col-sm-3 padding0">
    <button id="downloadModel" class="btn btn-md btn-default"
            style="height:100px;width: 210px" 
            ng-click="downloadWorkModel()">
          Download Work Model
    </button>
</span>
```

CODE:

```
$scope.downloadWorkModel= function(){
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+$scope.workData.image;
  document.body.appendChild(image);
  console.log("image width: "+image.width); //coming 0
  console.log("image height: "+image.height); //coming 0
  var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm");
  pdf.addImage(image, 'png', 0, 0);
  pdf.save('workModel.pdf');
};
```

NOTE:

This doesn't work either (it doesn't goes inside onload)-

```
$scope.downloadWorkModel= function(){
    var image = new Image();
    var width, height;
    image.onload = function() {
        width= this.width;
        height= this.height;
    };
    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+$scope.workData.image;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    console.log("image width: "+image.width); //coming 0
    console.log("image height: "+image.height); //coming 0
    var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", [width, height]);
    pdf.addImage(image, 'png', 0, 0);
    pdf.save('workModel.pdf');
};
```

@mplungjan-

After putting your code the download pdf content becomes too small to view-

[image]

Comment: If you use onload, you need to set the onload before setting the src

Comment: yes I did that..but it is not going inside onload method if I do so.

Comment: @Andreas- already changed my question as you write..Please check above.

Comment: The `console.log()` is not in the `load` handler and is therefor executed before the image has been loaded. Why would you expect it to show the correct size if the size is not known at that moment of time?

Comment: `console.log()` is not in `load` handler but if I put it inside `load` handler I can see that it is not getting inside handler. I expect to get the size of the image which is in `$scope.workData.image` so that I can set that size in my pdf because my image is dynamic so I can't simply set same size for all. It doesn't matter at which time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The load is async enough to not show the size until after the load

```js
$scope.downloadWorkModel = function() {
  var image = new Image();
  var width, height;
  image.onload = function() {
    width = this.width;
    height = this.height;
    document.body.appendChild(this);
    console.log("image width: " + width);
    console.log("image height: " +height);
    var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", [width, height]);
    pdf.addImage(this, 'png', 0, 0);
    if (done) {  // something needs to decide when this is true
      pdf.save('workModel.pdf'); 
    }
  };
  image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + $scope.workData.image;
};
```

Comment: so every time image is load a pdf is created.

Comment: Then the `pdf.save('workModel.pdf');` has to be called after the last onload has finished.

Comment: After putting your code, the onload is getting executed but the zoom level is `6.15%` which is too small to view. I want it to be 75% so that the image is clearly viewable. See updated question.

Comment: If the  $scope.workData.image is too small then I guess you can enlarge it by multiplying the height and width with a number - it will likely be blurry though

Comment: or if we set the zoom level of image.src then that should also work. But is it doable?

Comment: I have no idea. I just fixed the async part of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.downloadWorkModel= function(){
      let image = new Image();
      let width, height;
      image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+$scope.workData.image;
      let addedImage = document.body.appendChild(image);
      width = addedImage.width;
      height = addedImage.height;
      console.log("image width: "+width); //coming 0
      console.log("image height: "+height); //coming 0
      var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", [width, height]);
      pdf.addImage(image, 'png', 0, 0);
      pdf.save('workModel.pdf');
    };
```

Comment: can we set the zoom level of PDF using jsPDF? Using your changes, the PDF zoom level is too low to be viewable.

Comment: or if we set the zoom level of `image.src` then that should also work. But is it doable?